# Setting up triple monitors with a Display Link Adapter

Tags: multiple-monitors, displaylink

My first question, I suppose, is "Is this setup even possible?" I'm running a Dell N7010 with Ubuntu 12.10 and I have two external monitors. One of them is connected with a VGA cable and is running perfectly. The other is connected with a DisplayLink adapter and the monitor has a green screen.

Here is the xorg.conf that I hacked together

```
Section "ServerLayout"   
    Identifier      "threescreens"
    Screen          "VGA" 0 0
    Screen          "Laptop" RightOf "Laptop"
    Screen          "DisplayLink" LeftOf "Laptop" 0 0
    InputDevice     "keyboard" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice     "mouse" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Device"
   Identifier      "DisplayLinkDevice"
   Driver          "fbdev"
   BusID           "Video Bus"               # needed to use multiple DisplayLink devices 
   Option          "fbdev" "/dev/fb0"  # change to whatever device you want to use
  Option          "rotate" "CCW"      # uncomment for rotation
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier  "DisplayLink"
Device      "DisplayLinkDevice"
HorizSync   31-101
    VertRefresh 60-160
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "DisplayLink"
    Device          "Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth           24
        Virtual         1680x1050
   EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier  "Laptop"
Device      "Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller"
HorizSync   31-101
    VertRefresh 60-160
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Laptop"
    Device          "Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth           24
        Virtual         1680x1050
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier  "VGA"
Device      "Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller"
HorizSync   31-101
    VertRefresh 60-160
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "VGA"
    Device          "Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth           24
        Virtual         1680x1050
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

When I boot the boot screen appears on every screen, but when it finishes booting none of the screens display anything, but they are on.
What is my best course of action here?